# To fix Navigation menu of PyCharm

Tags: pycharm, jetbrains-ide

I cannot fix the PyCharm navigation menu?

[image: image of PyCharm editor]

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Can you please explain exactly what the problem is? To me it's not clear from the image.

Answer (score 0):

It seems like you played roughly with your settings....

I do not know how to solve it, but to access your settings, use Ctrl+Alt+S, after accessing your settings, you will be able to remember where you roughly played. Else, if its their problem, a restart will solve it

Answer (score 0):

**As I understand you did hide the main menu and do not know how to bring it back.**

To bring the Main Menu back:

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl + Shift + A</kbd> to open `Find Action...` popup (or <kbd>Shift</kbd> 2 times in a row and switch to `Actions` tab)
2. Type `main menu` there and select `View | Appearance: Main Menu` to put Main Menu bar back.

   [image]

   Alternatively just use the first entry (`Main menu`) to bring Main Menu as a popup and do whatever you want there:

   [image]